# Wix package ID for .NET core runtime 1.0.3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core, wix, wix3.5

I have an ASP.NET MVC app and I'm using WiX to create the installer. I had to install .NET Framework 4.6.1 on the host machine so I specified the WiX package id on the .wxs file:

```
<PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx461Web"/>
```

I also need to install .NET core runtime 1.0.3 to run the MVC app on IIS (otherwise I get an 500.19 error)

What's the id for such package?

Here the link to the runtime package:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

How am I supposed to know the WiX `PackageGroupRef` id for a given package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiX doesn't currently come with package groups for .NET Core. You have to write the `ExePackage` elements by hand.

Comment: once I have the ExePackage in place, how can I trigger it?

Comment: Make it a child of your `Chain`.